# Angular 11: Dexie Dynamically created stores, Getting InvalidTableError while performing search on table

Tags: angular11, dexie

I have create stores dynamically in the database.

```
try {
          if (!(await existingCollection).includes(tableName)) {
            const dbVersion = this.collectionsDb.verno + 1;
            await this.collectionsDb.close();
            await this.collectionsDb.version(dbVersion).stores({
              [tableName]: '++_id,' + replaceAll(element.headerNames.join(',').toLowerCase(), '[^a-zA-Z,]', ''),
            });
            localStorage.setItem('collectionDbVersion', dbVersion.toString());
            await this.collectionsDb.open();
            await this.collectionsDb[tableName].bulkAdd(csvDataArray);
          } else {
            await this.collectionsDb[tableName].clear();
            await this.collectionsDb[tableName].bulkAdd(csvDataArray);
          }
          existingStoresData.push({
            collectionId: tableName
          });

        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Unable to create collection:\n' + JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
        }
```

I am able to perform search when database gets created for first time.

But when I refresh the page (this time neither any new table created nor update the DB version) and trying to perform search, I am getting **InvalidTableError - table does not exist** even though I can see the table in database.

Please refer the error description below

> DexieError {_e: Error
> at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12)
> at new DexieError (ht…, name: "InvalidTableError", message: "Table collection_6135f2c6166805000120ab45 does not exist", inner: null, _promise: DexiePromise, …}
> inner: null
> message: "Table collection_6135f2c6166805000120ab45 does not exist"
> name: "InvalidTableError"
> _e: Error at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12) at new DexieError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57048:19) at CollectionsDatabase.push.Texg.Dexie.table (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60875:19) at http://localhost:4200/main.js:11795:48 at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57836:23 at callListener (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57559:19) at endMicroTickScope (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57631:25) at physicalTick (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57614:30) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9743:30) at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:108914:33)
> stack: "Error\n    at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12)\n    at new DexieError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57048:19)\n    at CollectionsDatabase.push.Texg.Dexie.table (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60875:19)\n    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:11795:48\n    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57836:23\n    at callListener (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57559:19)\n    at endMicroTickScope (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57631:25)\n    at physicalTick (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57614:30)\n    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9743:30)\n    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:108914:33)"
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> _promise: DexiePromise
> onuncatched: ƒ nop()
> _PSD: {id: "global", global: true, ref: 19, unhandleds: Array(0), onunhandled: ƒ, …}
> _lib: false
> _listeners: []
> _numPrev: 2
> _prev: DexiePromise {_listeners: Array(0), _lib: false, _PSD: {…}, _stackHolder: Error at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12) at new DexiePromise (…, onuncatched: ƒ, …}
> _stackHolder: Error at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12) at new DexiePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57271:29) at DexiePromise.then (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57297:22) at CollectionsService.isColumnExists (http://localhost:4200/main.js:11794:35) at CollectionsService. (http://localhost:4200/main.js:11686:42) at Generator.next () at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:135975:71 at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:10339:33) at __awaiter (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:135971:12) at http://localhost:4200/main.js:11683:148
> _state: false
> _value: DexieError
> inner: null
> message: "Table collection_6135f2c6166805000120ab45 does not exist"
> name: "InvalidTableError"
> _e: Error at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12) at new DexieError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57048:19) at CollectionsDatabase.push.Texg.Dexie.table (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60875:19) at http://localhost:4200/main.js:11795:48 at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57836:23 at callListener (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57559:19) at endMicroTickScope (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57631:25) at physicalTick (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57614:30) at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9743:30) at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:108914:33)
> stack: "Error\n    at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12)\n    at new DexieError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57048:19)\n    at CollectionsDatabase.push.Texg.Dexie.table (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60875:19)\n    at http://localhost:4200/main.js:11795:48\n    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57836:23\n    at callListener (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57559:19)\n    at endMicroTickScope (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57631:25)\n    at physicalTick (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57614:30)\n    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9743:30)\n    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:108914:33)"
> [[Prototype]]: Object
> _promise: DexiePromise {_listeners: Array(0), _lib: false, _PSD: {…}, _stackHolder: Error at getErrorWithStack (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:56951:12) at new DexiePromise (…, onuncatched: ƒ, …}
> stack: (...)
> get stack: ƒ ()
> [[Prototype]]: DexieError
> stack: (...)
> then: (...)
> [[Prototype]]: Dexie.Promise
> stack: (...)
> get stack: ƒ ()